# Spring Boot can't find my autowired class (Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Spring's autowire annotation in my test class in order to inject an instance of a class.

```
package com.mycom.mycust.processing.tasks.references;

public class ReferenceIdentifierTest {

    @Autowired
    private FormsDB formsDB;

    @PostConstruct
    @Test
    public void testCreateTopLevelReferencesFrom() throws Exception {
        ReferenceIdentifier referenceIdentifier = new ReferenceIdentifier(formsDB);
    }
}
```

This is the FormsDB class:

```
package com.mycom.mycust.mysql;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Component
public class FormsDB extends KeyedDBTable<Form> {

    public FormsDB(ConnectionFactory factory) throws SQLException {
        super(factory.from("former", new FormsObjectMapper()));
    }
}
```

And here is the SpringBootApplication class:

```
package com.mycom.mycust.processing;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.mycom.mycust")
public class Processing implements CommandLineRunner {
    // Code
}
```

When I run my test, `formsDB` is null. Since I've used the `PostConstruct` annotation on the test function I think that FormsDB could not be autowired due to the class not being found. There is also an IntelliJ warning on the `Autowired` annotation in test class: `Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service...)`. But I have put the `Component` annotation above the `FormsDB` class and I've also put the path `com.mycom.mycust` in the `ComponentScan` annotation of the SpringBootApplication. So I can't see why it can't find the class.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have @PostConstruct on the test method? That does not make sense

Comment: I thought that that would make sure the autowiring was done before the test function was run.

Comment: No. I will add the correct answer right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test calls is missing some important annotations to make autowiring work:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ReferenceIdentifierTest {

    @Autowired
    private FormsDB formsDB;

    @Test
    public void testCreateTopLevelReferencesFrom() throws Exception {
        ReferenceIdentifier referenceIdentifier = new ReferenceIdentifier(formsDB);
    }
}
```

also you can remove @PostConstruct that does not make sense in a test.